# Example: truncated second moment exists but the second factorial moment does not

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Consider some $\mathbb{N}_0$-valued random variable $X$. I am looking for an example where $$ \sum_{k=a}^\infty k^2 P(X=k) < \infty$$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}_0$, i.e. the truncated second moment of $X$ exists, but $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1) P(X=k) = \infty,$$ i.e. the second factorial moment does not exist. I guess, a very similar, if not identical, question would be, when the truncated second moment exists, but the ordinary (not truncated) second moment does not. Any ideas?

Edit: As pointed out in a comment, there is no such example. (Should I delete this question then?)

Comment: Is there a reason you start at $k=a$ for the top sum and $k=0$ for the bottom?

Comment: Yes, the top sum is supposed to be the truncated second moment. Therefore, I "cut" the sum off at value $a$.

Comment: It is clear that $\sum_{k=0}^a k(k-1) P(X=k) < \infty$ so the second factorial moment is finite iff $\sum_{k=a}^\infty k(k-1) P(X = k) < \infty$. But $k(k-1) P(X=k) < k^2P(X=k)$ so just comparison of sums tells you that this is finite when the truncated second moment exists.

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks.

Comment: No, there's no need to delete the question. If you understood the answer, you can write it up yourself, post it as an answer and accept it so the question doesn't remain unanswered. Or you could tell the person who answered in a comment that their comment answered your question and you'd accept it if they post it as an answer. (Since you didn't ping them with `@`, they may not have seen your response.)